# Exceljs - Formulas do not get updated depending on position of cells

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, excel-formula, exceljs

I have a Excel file where I need to enter certain values from a JSON file. The excel sheet has pre-defined formulas that will use the values I will enter from JSON file using Exceljs.

Now I know that Exceljs doesn't do calculation. But here's the problem. Let's take an example to understand better.

A1 = 5

B1 = 4

C1 = 7

E1 = (A1+B1+C1) / 3 ----> *which means the value of E1 = 5.33*

Excel (or any spreadsheet really) gives us the convenience of dragging a formula cell and spreading it down the column and the formula automatically changes to, say,

E2 = (A2+B2+C2) / 3

E3 = (A3+B3+C3) / 3

E4 = (A4+B4+C4) / 3
*and so on...*

But, when I access these cells in exceljs, the formula they show is,

E2 = (A1+B1+C1) / 3

E3 = (A1+B1+C1) / 3

And their shareType is set to shared.

Is there anyway to update these shared formula depending on position of cell.

These cells only get updated to correct formula when I open the file in excel and then very intentionally click on the formula and accept the formula. Then the formula is recognized by exceljs correctly and the formula is not 'shared' anymore in the shareType.

Any feedback or help here will be appreciated. If you know of another library which can recognize these kind of shared formula will also be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: hard to say.. try adding [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @traynor I mean, adding a minimal example feels silly here. If you have used exceljs, the code is very basic - and for it to make sense, I will then have to add the minimal excel file too. I feel like it might become to confusing. If you know what I mean.

Comment: it's not silly, it shows your approach, and then helps others locate the problem. it this case, a few lines that create the formula would help, to know is it by iterating, or `fillFormula` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try creating each formula manually, and also setting cell reference while iterating data:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

    worksheet.getCell(`E${i}`).value = {
        formula: `(A${i}+B${i}+C${i})/3`
    };
    
}
```

Comment: Alright, you did understand what I was getting at. Thanks for the input despite me not being helpful haha.
But in the end, we do need to manually go through the cells and set up the formulas. I am not even sure what some of excel's formula translates into.. But that's a different problem.

Comment: I did discover something meanwhile. If I modify the excel file in exceljs, and then open the excel file, in my case with LibreOffice, and trigger a force save and then, return back to exceljs to access the predefined formula - they are calculated properly. Perhaps I will need to write a bash script.